# Implementing IntoIterator on a reference to struct that wraps a HashMap

Tags: rust, iterator, lifetime, borrow-checker, ownership

I'm attempting to build a sort of HTTP web server as a learning exercise and I'm having trouble trying to make one of my types iterable using a for loop (by implementing `IntoIterator`).

#### So far

I've created a data structure whereby I have a `Response` object (meant to model a HTTP response), and that contains a `Headers` object (meant to model the HTTP response headers), and that contains a `HashMap<String, String>`, representing the actual header values:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Headers {
    headers: HashMap<String, String>,
}

impl Headers {
    pub fn new(headers: HashMap<String, String>) -> Self {
        Self { headers }
    }
}

struct Response {
    headers: Headers,
}

impl Response {
    pub fn new(headers: Headers) -> Self {
        Self { headers }
    }

    pub fn headers(&self) -> &Headers {
        &self.headers
    }
}
```

Note: The `headers` method returns an immutable reference because I just want to read the values. I ideally don't want to copy/clone the headers just so that they can be read.

#### Aim

What I want to be able to do is something like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    // just creating an example here
    let mut headers = HashMap::new();
    headers.insert("foo".to_string(), "one".to_string());
    headers.insert("bar".to_string(), "two".to_string());
    let response = Response::new(Headers::new(headers));

    // this is what I'm aiming for:
    for (key, value) in response.headers() {
        println!("{}: {}", key, value);
    }
}
```

#### What I've tried

I've tried a whole bunch of things to get this working, but I've so far failed. The closest I've come so far is to implement `IntoIterator` for `&Headers` and then call `into_iter()` on the hash map:

```rust
impl IntoIterator for &Headers {
    type Item = (String, String);
    type IntoIter = IntoIter<String, String>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.headers.into_iter()
    }
}
```

However, this results in an error:

> cannot move out of `self.headers` which is behind a shared reference

I've tried searching around and found numerous StackOverflow questions that are similar, but none of them seem to answer my exact question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're doing right now is delegating to the `IntoIterator` implementation of `HashMap<String, String>`. But you need to delegate to the `IntoIterator` implementation of `&HashMap<String, String>` because you can't get at an owned version of `self.headers` when `self` is a reference.

This is an easy fix though, thankfully:

```
// Just giving this type a concise name so we can reference it easyily later
type HeaderMap = HashMap<String, String>;


impl<'h> IntoIterator for &'h Headers {
    // Here we just tell Rust to use the types we're delegating to.
    // This is just (&'h String, &'h String)
    type Item = <&'h HeaderMap as IntoIterator>::Item;
    type IntoIter = <&'h HeaderMap as IntoIterator>::IntoIter;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        // Now just call `into_iter` on the correct thing
        (&self.headers).into_iter()
        // self.headers.iter() would work just as well here
    }
}
```